# Java NumberFormat instance creation

Tags: java, currency, number-formatting

Got this doubt during using NumberFormat and Locale class
What is the difference between this approach

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFomat.getCurrencyInstance();
nf.setCurrency(Currency.getInstance(Locale.US));
String us = getCurrency().getDisplayName();
```

And this approach

```
NumberFormat us = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);
```

Comment: Is that third line of code in first snippet really needed? If not, delete. Keep your Question as simple and as pointed as possible, with no distractions.

Comment: The first version has two errors that cause it to not compile.  `NumberFomat` and `getCurrency()` are both undefined.  The difference, therefore, is that the first approach will lead to a compilation error and the second will produce a `NumberFormat` instance that prints numbers as currency as dictated by the US locale.

Answer (score 1):

## Java 1.1 versus 1.4

One appears to be legacy code from Java 1.1, the other more modern from Java 1.4.

The [`NumberFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/NumberFormat.html) class and its [`getCurrencyInstance()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/NumberFormat.html#getCurrencyInstance()) method appear to both date back to Java 1.1.

The [`Currency`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Currency.html) class was not added to Java until Java 1.4. So the [`NumberFormat#setCurrency`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/NumberFormat.html#getCurrencyInstance(java.util.Locale)) method did not arrive until Java 1.4.

I glanced quickly through the Javadoc, and did not see any guidance. I do not know the full story here. But I would be inclined to use the newer code. I would explicitly get my `Currency` instance, and pass to `setCurrency`. But perhaps someone else will post a better Answer explaining if there is actually any practical difference.

---

By the way, heed the caution to the bottom of the description of `Currency` class:

> It is recommended to use BigDecimal class while dealing with Currency or monetary values as it provides better handling of floating point numbers and their operations.